# How can I draw snake arrow in automata using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I find:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->,decorate,decoration=snake] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

in TikZ manual, but dose not work! How can i draw snake edges in automata using tikz?

Comment: Did you load the appropriate `\tikzlibrary`?

Comment: Can you please add your full document starting from `\documentclass{..... \emd{document}` into your question?

Comment: @percusse Well for some reason or the other, it does not compile on my computer if I do not load `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}`.

Comment: @azetina You are right I was loading `pgfplots` and somehow it goes through.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following code compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\usepackage{pgfplots} %% Using pgfplots package alone works as well.

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->,decorate,decoration=snake] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This yields the output in the manual.

[image]

But as the manual suggests,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,post length=1mm}]
(0,0) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

yields a better output as follows:

[image]