# Create a zig-zag line

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to create a line like this in latex?

[image]

Comment: probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68890/how-can-i-draw-snake-arrow-in-automata-using-tikz

Comment: The pgfmanual is full of similar looking things, see section 48.2 Path Morphing Decorations. Do they already provide what you're looking for? If not, could you please be more specific? And tell us more precisely what you are looking for?

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/138900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you haven't really placed any constraints on it whatsoever, which frees me up to do silly approaches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\def\z{\kern2.1pt}
\def\tmp{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont U\z U\z U\z U\z}
$\bullet$\kern-8.5pt%
\stackengine{-5pt}{\kern9.4pt\tmp}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\tmp}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}
\end{document}
```

[image]